# Do I have to make a local version of my website before I can use Xdebug?

Tags: php, debugging, joomla, xdebug

I am trying to find out a way to debug my joomla powered website. This is a very new field for me, so I am following the "Using an IDE" steps on this page: https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_debug_your_code and some other related pages(For configuring eclipse, xdebug, etc..).

As the page suggests, xdebug is a prevailing tool for debugging. I have never heard it before,  now the only thing I know about it is that it is an extension of PHP which help debug. I noticed that in my XAMPP installation, xdebug is installed(at least there is a xdebug section in php.ini), however, in my webspace, there is no xdebug section in php.ini. So my questions are:

1) Being there no xdebug section in php.ini of my webspace, does this mean my webserver doesn't support xdebug? If yes, is there any web hosting company that has xdebug available, or at least offer this possibility?

2) Regardless of xdebug, is it possible to debug(set breakpoint, watch variables, etc..) PHP files in a joomla site in a remote server? Is it a common practice to clone the site to local before debugging it?

3) My xampp control panel version is 3.2.1. About xdebug configuration in XAMPP, on this page https://docs.joomla.org/Edit_PHP.INI_File_for_XDebug it says "For Windows, it should look like the example below:

```
[XDebug]
;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
zend_extension_ts="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

However, the xdebug section in my php.ini looks like this

```
[XDebug]
;zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
;xdebug.remote_enable = 0
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"
```

How should I edit it in order to enable xdebug? Specifically do I need to set "remote port"?

Comment: You wouldn't normally be doing debugging on a live site because you wouldn't be writing code there.  You wouldn't use code on a live site unless it was working. So yes the normal thing is to debug locally. However you are right that sometimes your live site stops working or has a problem that you want to handle.  You can certainly log debugging information on your server, but you want to be very very careful about it since it is often a lot of lines.  In your joomla backend check phpinfo to see if xdebug is somewhere on the server.

Comment: I confirmed with the hosting, xdebug is not installed. I asked them how can  install xdebug, they said its beyond their custom service scope. Looks like I have to have access to the server command line to install xdebug, right?

Comment: Honestly you do not want to be debugging there. It's not an environment set up for coding, it is an environment set up for webhosting.  If you are getting some kind of error, turn on logging where you think it is coming from.  Also check your apache error logs and see what you see.